# Ember save returns multiple objects

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember 1.9 with Ember-data 1.0.0-beta.11.

My REST resource accepts a POSTed record and will return the persisted object, which is normally handled fine by Ember.

However, *sometimes*, the REST resource will determine that two records must be created and will do so, returning two records in the POST response.

I'm trying to determine the best course of action in this case.  As it happens, both records are inserted into the store.  However, the response to the `save`'s `resolve` function is a single record (the first one in the response).

Without concern for the theoretical 'correctness' of the REST resource, and assuming that modification of that resource is not possible, how can I handle this in Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a record, Ember Data applies `extractSave` serializer hook to the response, which by default uses `extractSingle` method to extract record: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.11/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L877.

You can try to overwrite `extractSave` hook in your serializer, investigate payload to figure out how many records have been returned. If it's a single record, then use `this.extractSingle()` otherwise use `this.extractArray()`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Not the cleanest solution but it works.  The `resolve` function from the `save` gets a single object of the type (using `Ember.inspect`), but with a null id.  The `data` property contains an array of the records returned by the server.  So while not clean, I can deal with this.  Thanks for your answer!